# imo Messenger can't do Skype IM anymore, any alternatives?

Tags: skype, imo-instant-messenger

I used [imo messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imo.android.imoim) to chat (instant messages) with my Skype contacts, but this feature is now unavailable.

The real Skype client sucks my battery dry in no time.

Any recommendations for further alternatives to log in or federate with Skype? I don't need voice or video calls, just text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [IM+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.shapeservices.impluslite)?

It mentions that for the Skype function you need to use an in-app purchase. However it has good reviews overall, however I'm not sure what the battery drain is like.

Comment: The free version of IM+ does not support skype, not even instant messaging in skype.